# Different result from expected output in an insert query code in Python x MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

So I'm reading a book and so far the code is

```
>>> dbconfig = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'user' : 'vsearch',
        'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
        'database': 'vsearchlogDB', }
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> _SQL = """show tables"""
>>> cursor.execute(_SQL)
>>> res = cursor.fetchall()
>>> res
[('log',)]
>>> _SQL = """describe log"""
>>> cursor.execute(_SQL)
>>> res = cursor.fetchall()
>>> res
[('id', 'int', 'NO', 'PRI', None, 'auto_increment'), ('ts', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DEFAULT_GENERATED'), ('phrase', 'varchar(128)', 'NO', '', None, ''), ('letters', 'varchar(32)', 'NO', '', None, ''), ('ip', 'varchar(16)', 'NO', '', None, ''), ('browser_string', 'varchar(256)', 'NO', '', None, ''), ('results', 'varchar(64)', 'NO', '', None, '')]
>>> for row in res:
    print(row)

    
('id', 'int', 'NO', 'PRI', None, 'auto_increment')
('ts', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DEFAULT_GENERATED')
('phrase', 'varchar(128)', 'NO', '', None, '')
('letters', 'varchar(32)', 'NO', '', None, '')
('ip', 'varchar(16)', 'NO', '', None, '')
('browser_string', 'varchar(256)', 'NO', '', None, '')
('results', 'varchar(64)', 'NO', '', None, '')
>>> _SQL = """insert into log
(phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results)
values
(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
>>> cursor.execute(_SQL, ('hitch-hiker', 'xyz', '127.0.0.1', 'Safari', 'set()'))
>>> conn.commit()
>>> _SQL = """select * from log"""
>>> cursor.execute(_SQL)
>>> for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

and my result was

```
(1, datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 25, 11, 26, 5), 'hitch-hiker', 'xyz', '127.0.0.1', 'Safari', 'set()')
```

I'm just confused because the expected result displayed in the book should be (abridged):

```
(1, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, ..., "{'e', 'i'}")
(2, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, ..., 'set()')
```

How come it's expected that MySQL automatically determines the correct value for the set() result? But in my result shows otherwise.

By the way, the webapp code is supposed to find vowels in a provided word

```
def search4letters(phrase: str, letters: str='aeiou') -> set:
    """Return a set of the 'letters' found in 'phrase'."""
    return set(letters).intersection(set(phrase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an oversight (of the book writer)?

The expected result has 2 rows, but you have only one, but in your code you have only one "Insert" statement and I could not find any place where e. g. 'e' from the first expected result row is mentionned in your code.

Comment: I don't know if it's an oversight. But given the code I just followed, what really SHOULD be the output?